# j2ee.server.home missing during NetBean project build

Tags: jakarta-ee, ant, jenkins

I'm using Jenkins to build a Java EE application I develop using NetBeans.
When I try to use Ant to build the project on the CI server I get the following error:

> The Java EE server classpath is not correctly set up - server home directory is missing.
>   Either open the project in the IDE and assign the server or setup the server classpath manually.
>   For example like this:
>      ant -Dj2ee.server.home=<app_server_installation_directory>

I'm trying to run the **dist** target to create the war file of my service. I don't want to deploy it to the application server, yet.

Comment: this needs more info: relevant parts of he build file and especially the target of the buildfile that echos that error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just ran into this build issue on Jenkins with a Netbean Java EE Application.  I'm developing on a Windows machine but Jenkins installed on Linux.  Basically the solution is to ensure JavaEE App Server is installed on the CI Server and then set the Ant build properties to point the installed App Server.

I resolved this error for my setup by:

- load GlassFish on my Linux CI server

  - # wget http://download.java.net/glassfish/3.1.2/release/glassfish-3.1.2.zip
  - # unzip glassfish-3.1.2.zip
  - # mv glassfish3 /usr/share/
- set app server install directory in Jenkin's job configuration

  - navigate to the **Job** and select the **Configure** option
  - under **Build** -> **Invoke Ant** -> press **Advanced...** button
  - add to the **Properties** = **j2ee.server.home=/usr/share/glassfish3/glassfish**

Answer (score 1):

If you are using netBeans Ide, then right click on the project. click properties. in the properties menu select Run. in that the first text box is server. There select the server. with which u want to run the project. If the server details are not configured before. configure server details and try. it wil help you to solve the above problem.

Comment: For me, only going to Properties > Run > Close fixed the issue. I already had GlassFish selected as server, but apparently it wasn't recognized yet... or something. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

To Solve this issue is very simple.

1. Right click on the Project -> Properties -> Run
2. And Change the server Setting from the current server to another sever and click OK.
3. Wait for any background scanning to finish.

Repeat the processes 1 to 3 again this time selecting the actual server you want to run the code on.

Then try Re-Running your application.